# differential drive vehicle in screen coords

Tags: modeling, simulation, kinematics

[differential drive vehicle in world frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxHbV.png)

what would change in the kinematic model of the differential drive vehicle if i  wanted to simulate it
using pygame module in python ( pygame or opencv or any other one )

**`x_dot = (vl+vr)/2*cos(theta)`**

**`y_dot = (vl+vr)/2*sin(theta)`**

**`theta_dot = (vr-vl)/w`**

vr is the velocity of the right wheel

vl is the velocity of the left wheel

theta is the heading angle

it uses a screen coords system which start at the top left corner of the screen insted of the lower left
my initial guess is since only the y axis is inverted then i should invert the sign of the y_dot

i hope i explained my question clearly the picture is in the link above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kinematics equation should remain the same. The only problem I see is with the third equation which should be

`theta_dot = (vr-vl)/W`

What you need to consider on top of those equations since you are working with screen pixels is:

- relationship of x and y with screen pixels (units should be $\frac{\text{x units}}{pixel}$, $\frac{\text{y units}}{pixel}$ or the inverse).
- you'd need to add variables for monitoring the position (preferably floats). e.g:

```
x = 0.0 
y = 0.0
```

- you'd need to integrate in time with respect to the position

```
x = x+ x_dot*dt
y = y+ y_dot*dt
theta = theta+ theta_dot*dt
```

where `dt` is the timestep you want to use.

- then you'd just need to redraw the vehicle at the orientation of theta (after you cast x, y to integers).

Comment: thank you very much as for the theta_dot ( my bad i just miss writen it in the post ) , but when i execute the simulation things are bit reversed , when i increase Vr the vehicle turne to the right insted of the left so when i inverse the sign of the y_dot or write theta_dot = (vr-vl )/w insted of (vl-vr) /w things seem to workout well , my only explanation for this is the frame change between the world and screen

Comment: the equations are written with x positive to the right, and y upwards. however the screen uses y- **downwards** as positive. That makes the two be reversed.